# Cordova Android : Unable to load External Images in Release App

Tags: cordova, android-webview, cordova-plugins

Am working on hybrid mobile app built on cordova framework, getting strange issue

in release app external images are not loading

i added below attributes in config file also added CSP in index.html

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<access origin="*" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

But still external images are not loading , if i put same url in browser m able to see images

I have referred many links which are posted in stackoverflow but still not able to find solution

Comment: You should put `allow-navigation ` and `access` tags into `config.xml` file, not `index.html`. Also please add console.log errors to your question.

Comment: i added allow-navigation and access in config.xml only, i will not be able to get logs because in release app only am getting this issue